# What's the difference between Time on Screen and Session Duration on Google Analytics for Apps?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for Android apps. On the App Overview page, it shows average Session Duration of about 45 seconds:

[image: average session duration]

However, once I click the "User Engagement" link above, it shows average Time on Screen of 1 minute and 47 seconds.

[image: average time on screen]

What's the difference between those two, and how can it be so different?

Comment: Your avg. session duration `45` is lower than avg time on screen? `1:47` That shouldn't be..

Comment: @donfuxx Yes, that's really weird. I wonder if I misunderstood them.

Comment: I have just looked through my apps analytics and there the avg. time on screen is smaller than avg. session duration. Makes sense since a user can watch multiple screens within one session. Is there maybe a problem with your analytics integration?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Avg Time on Page > Avg Session Duration. Implies Number of pages per session is less than 1. I only visited half a page? I am misunderstanding something

Answer (score 3):

#### Time on Screen:

Evaluate the performance of each screen in your app. This report count every each screen usage  metrics, like the number of Screen Views, Unique Screen Views, and the % Exit from a Screen.

#### Session Duration:

This is count total duration is calculated as follows:

For example:

```
App Page 1: first hit: 10:00 AM
App Page 2: first hit: 10:05 AM
App Page 3: first hit: 10:10 AM
```

10:00 - 10:15 = a visit duration of 15 minutes (***Total Session Duration***).

#### [This page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en) might help you more

thank you.

Comment: Incomplete explanation. The session duration depends on whether user has a measurable interaction with page 3.

Answer (score 0):

Have been asking myself the same question and then I've started playing with customizing my dashboard and found some useful information. When you add a new widget to your dashboard you have the ability to "Add a metric" in which you can type whatever metric you want (in this case the avg session duration and avg time on screen). When selected, you can hover your mouse cursor over an "i" icon which will show you the following hints for both metrics in question:

**Avg. Session Duration**
The length of a session. After a session starts, it can last as long as activity is tracked. By default, a web session is closed after 30 minutes of inactivity. For mobile apps, a session times out after 30 seconds of inactivity or with the app running in the background. Any activity that happens after a session is closed is tracked in a new session. You can change the default session timeout length in your account. App developers can also customize the timeout length in the Android and iOS SDKs.

**Avg. Time on Screen**
The average amount of time users spent on a screen.